# Add annotation to generated toString, hashCode and equals in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, tostring, hashcode

I regularly use generate toString and generate hashCode and equals methods from the drop down in eclipse. Our code quality tool examines these methods and marks us down for cyclic complexity. The easy way around this is to add a @SuppressWarnings("all") annotation to the method

This is the generated code

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("ExportServerJpa [protocol=").append(protocol)
            .append(", serverName=").append(serverName).append(", port=")
            .append(port).append(", keyPhrase=").append(keyPhrase)
            .append("]");
    return builder.toString();
}
```

This is what we have to check in

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("all")
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("ExportServerJpa [protocol=").append(protocol)
            .append(", serverName=").append(serverName).append(", port=")
            .append(port).append(", keyPhrase=").append(keyPhrase)
            .append("]");
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Can eclipse be set to include the @SuppressWarnings("all") annotation by default

We can't amend our code quality system to ignore these methods

Comment: The whole point of having a code quality tool is lost when you try to work around the metric which is causing it to fail. Most of the code quality tools are very configurable. Which metric of the code quality tool is failing?

Comment: Its the cyclomatic complexity and if statements must have braces rules. I understand the reasoning behind the check and for code we have written ourselves we ensure we meet these standards. But for generated code it seems pointless to have to split an equals method into sub methods because you have too many if statements in a method

Comment: How can such a method with a single code path without any conditionals raise the *Cyclomatic complexity*? And what kind of code quality system will get *satisfied* by `@SuppressWarnings("all")` instead of raising all alarm bells on it? Really questionable…

Comment: That's a bit of a mickey mouse example that i happened to have open at the time. a better example would a different class that has 12 instance variables. It's generated equals method is 60 lines long and has 32 if/else if/else statements in it. Resulting in a warning on our code quality system

Answer (score 0):

I use javax.annotation.Generated annotation to avoid the problem in sonar but I keep all warnings like this.